# How to approach Redux + Microservices intercommunication

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

We are implementing an auction cloud service, that will receive **orders**, from an **external API service on demand**. Each received order is a **1:1 to an auction**.

We can have more than **2000 orders (auctions) per day**. 
we have decided to use **Microservices + Redux** to separate concerns between orders and auctions.

Bellow are the explanation of each service.

**External API**

Enternal API is just a website that pushes orders to our **Order Service** and receive updates from our **Order service** we have no control over it.

**Order service**

Orders has a bunch of information (properties) that the client (mobile app) use to get information to decide on joining an auction. for example, this is how an order can look like:

```
{
  id: 123,
  description: 'Some description',
  salePrice: 0,
  minPrice: 1000,
  openPrice: 500,
  status: 'active',
  address: 'Some address',
  file: '.../some-file.pdf',
  client: 'Joe Doe',
  notes: 'Some notes',
  createdAt: '12345678',
  pending: false,
  postpone: false,
  ...moreproperties
}
```

In the order service the **orders** can be updated (address, name, openPrice, minPrice, status, etc) by the server at any time **before the auction starts** via the **actions bellow**.

```
{ type: LOAD_ORDERS, orders }
{ type: PEND_ORDER, id }
{ type: POSTPONE_ORDER, id }
{ type: SET_ORDER_AUCTION, id, auction, salePrice }
{ type: UPDATE_ORDER, id, properties }
```

**Auction Service**

An auction object in this service can look like this:

```
{
  id: 'abcd',
  orderId: 123456,
  increment: 1,
  outBid: { agentId: 'b1', price: 545 },
  bestBid:{agentId: 'b2', price: 550 },
  openPrice: 500,
  currentPrice: 550,
  status: 'started'
  startedByAgent: 'a1'
}
```

Auctions can be updated by these actions:

```
{ type: JOIN_AUCTION, id, agentId, type }
{ type: START_AUCTION, id, agentId }
{ type: PLACE_BID, id, agentId, price }
{ type: END_AUCTION, id, agentId }
```

**API Service**

It works just as gateway between front end app and the microservices. Receive and dispatch requests from clients (mobiles) to **Order Service** or **Auction Service** in form of actions.

**Workflow:**

1 - **External API** push orders of the day to **Order Service** via LOAD_ORDERS also a CREATE_AUCTIONS action is dispatched to the **Action Service** to create an auction for each order.

2 - User open mobile app and get the list of orders of the day with details including open prices from **Order Service**.

3 - User join an specific order
   - **API Service** creates a **bidder** agent that will place bids.
   - **API Service** send a join action via JOIN_AUCTION to join an auction on the **Auction Service**

4 - An **auctioneer** agent starts the auction and bidding starts.

5 - Joined **bidder** agents starts to place bids via PLACE_BID action on **Auction Service**.

6 - When auction is over the **auctioneer** agent ends the auction by dispatching END_AUCTION.

7 - When auction ends sale price and auction details (via object) are send to the **Order Service** via the SET_ORDER_AUCTION.

8 - The **Order Service** handle the SET_ORDER_AUCTION and update the order state with the final **salePrice** and the **auction** object and then wait for payment.

9 - Once payment info is received from the client then it is submitted to the **External Service** by **Order Service**

**My questions are:**

- Is the workflow above a reasonable approach for using Microservices + Redux and updating each service state?
- It is ok to dispatch actions from a microservice to another when using redux microservices? My question is because when using microservices + event sourcing + CQRS, services intercommunication are not recommended but instead using a Sagas that work as intermediate service that convert events to commands.
- My other question is where to put business logic (validation), for example a bidder cannot send bid if auction is not started or its already ended, a bidder cannot send a bid if he/she has not joined the auction yet. Were to put this logic? in action, middleware or reducers? and how to handle errors back to clients?
- In general what are some best practices when it comes to Microservices + Redux?
- What are pros and cons of using **Microservices + Redux** vs **Microservices + Event sourcing + CQRS**?

Sorry for the long post, I just need some orientation here because I cannot find any documentation about this topic and I am not sure if I am approaching this right.

Any advice would be appreciated!!!

Comment: how did this work out??

Answer (score 0):

I think this questions is way off the guidelines.

Nevertheless, I'd say write your own redux middleware to integrate your microservices; the API is very simple:

```
store => next => action => {
  let result = next(action)
  return result
}
```

In the most outer function (`store =>`) you can add microservice listerner and dispatch actions via the store reference.
In the innermost function (`action =>`) you can react to actions in the redux app by sending requests to your microservices.